# Compress in Java, decompress in Python - snappy/redis-py-cluster

Tags: python, redis, redis-cluster, snappy, redis-py

I am writing cron script in python for a **redis cluster** and using [redis-py-cluster](https://github.com/Grokzen/redis-py-cluster) for only reading data from a prod server. A separate Java application is writing to redis cluster with **snappy compression and java string codec utf-8**.

I am able to read data but not able to decode it.

```
from rediscluster import RedisCluster
import snappy


host, port ="127.0.0.1", "30001"
startup_nodes = [{"host": host, "port": port}]
print("Trying connecting to redis cluster host=" + host +  ", port=" + str(port))

rc = RedisCluster(startup_nodes=startup_nodes, max_connections=32, decode_responses=True)
print("Connected",  rc)

print("Reading all keys, value ...\n\n")
for key in rc.scan_iter("uidx:*"):
   value = rc.get(key)
   #uncompress = snappy.uncompress(value, decoding="utf-8")
   print(key, value)
   print('\n')

print("Done. exit()")
exit()
```

`decode_responses=False` is working fine with the comment. however changing `decode_responses=True` is throwing error. My guess is its not able to get the correct decoder.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "splooks_cron.py", line 22, in <module>
print(key, rc.get(key))
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/redis/client.py", line 1207, in get
return self.execute_command('GET', name)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/rediscluster/utils.py", line 101, in inner
return func(*args, **kwargs)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/rediscluster/client.py", line 410, in execute_command
return self.parse_response(r, command, **kwargs)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/redis/client.py", line 768, in parse_response
response = connection.read_response()
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/redis/connection.py", line 636, in read_response
raise e
: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0x82 in position 0: invalid start byte
```

PS: Uncommenting this line `uncompress = snappy.uncompress(value, decoding="utf-8")` is breaking with error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "splooks_cron.py", line 27, in <module>
uncompress = snappy.uncompress(value, decoding="utf-8")
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/snappy/snappy.py", line 91, in uncompress
return _uncompress(data).decode(decoding)
snappy.UncompressError: Error while decompressing: invalid input
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After hours of debugging, I was finally able to solve this.

I am using [xerial/snappy-java](https://github.com/xerial/snappy-java) compressor in my Java code which is writing to **redis cluster**. Interesting thing is that during compression **xerial** `SnappyOutputStream` adds some *offset* at the beginning of the compress data. In my case this looks something like this

```
"\x82SNAPPY\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x01\xb6\x8b\x06\\******actual data here*****
```

Due to this, the decompressor was not able to figure out. I modified code as below and remove *offset* form the value. it's working fine now.

```
for key in rc.scan_iter("uidx:*"):
   value = rc.get(key) 
   #in my case offset was 20 and utf-8 is default ecoder/decoder for snappy 
   # https://github.com/andrix/python-snappy/blob/master/snappy/snappy.py
   uncompress_value = snappy.decompress(value[20:])
   print(key, uncompress_value)
   print('\n')
```